# 404 not found after installed cyberpanal

Tags: digital-ocean, openlitespeed, cyber-panel

I try to install **cyberpanal** in digitalocean droplet, but it does not install successfully.

After that when i visited my website a '404 not found' default page from LiteSpeed is shown. Also the Apache is not running

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfcSp.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an issue with installing the CyberPanel, please consider launching a CyberPanel from the marketplace directly. It should be much easier for you to setup a server.

CyberPanel uses OpenLiteSpeed as a default web server, so you should not expect an Apache run by default.

Before visiting the page, did you create a website on the control panel yet? If not, then a returned 404 status code is expected.
More, https://cyberpanel.net/docs/2-creating-website/

If you have more question for CyberPanel, I'd recommend you ask in their forum  https://community.cyberpanel.net/